# Defining a scala trait def that returns a concrete sub type instance

Tags: scala

I am attempting to define a base trait used for a simple CRUD system.  However, I need the base trait to support a "copyWithId" def (since the Scala case class magic for copy is not available).  The best approach I have found so far is:

```
trait Identifiable[ID, T] {
  def id: Option[ID]
  def copyWithId(id: Option[ID]): T
}

case class TestNamedIdentity(id: Option[Int], name: String) 
    extends Identifiable[Int, TestNamedIdentity] {

  def copyWithId(id: Option[Int]): TestNamedIdentity = {
    copy(id = id)
  }
}
```

This works but looks a bit clunky because it requires all the concrete instances to extend with ID and Self.  I'd like to write something like the following:

```
trait Identifiable[ID] {
  this:X =>
  def copyWithId(id: Option[ID]): X
  def id: Option[ID]
}
```

Using some form of self-reference to the concrete class.  Any way to make this work?

**Update: With use case below**

The idea is to use it in code like

```
abstract class SomeClass[A <: IdentifiableEntity[ID], ID] {
  def someFunc2: Option[ID]
  def someFunc(item: A): A = {
    item.copyWithId(someFunc2)
  }
}
```

Using the solution from @jwvh requires "asInstanceOf" casting after the call.  Which for my use case works, but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

```
    item.copyWithId(someFunc2).asInstanceOf[A]
```

Comment: The first form is the only one I know to work nicely when needing to write a parametric method involving an `Identifiable` that also returns `T`. Re-writing copy methods seems clunky, but doing the same with CRUD methods I thought to be worse, so I've dealt with it. Beyond that, the best I could think of to save some boilerplate would be a macro, but it would only save so much. Working with `copy` in an abstract manner is quite tricky.

Comment: @MichaelZajac I was afraid macro would be the only viable solution, and I'm not willing to add that level of confusion to the codebase.  I think jwvh's approach is at least cleaner for the api consumer than my first form above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work.

```
trait Identifiable[ID] {
  def id: Option[ID]
  def copyWithId(id: Option[ID]): Identifiable[ID]
}
```

Then the case class is simplified.

```
case class TestNamedIdentity(id: Option[Int], name: String
                            ) extends Identifiable[Int] {
  def copyWithId(id: Option[Int]): TestNamedIdentity = copy(id = id)
}
```

Comment: This does work, however, it then requires any usage to cast back.  For example: `saved.copyWithId(id).asInstanceOf[A]`.  So basically trading one boilerplate for another.  For the specific use case I'm working with this works.  Thanks

Comment: @rapidninja, I don't see it. The result type of `copyWithId()` is as defined in the case class. Why is casting required? Is `saved.copyWithId()` supposed to a different type than `saved`?

Comment: I added the example to the original post to explain the use case and why casting is required.

Comment: I have now implemented this using Macros, because there were several traits with similar functions (Audit, Owner, Identifiable, SoftDelete).  The Macro will mixin the call to copy with appropriate attributes at the compilation time and it reduces the boilerplate required for use.